# Select records with 2 type of sort

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, subquery

I have 2 tables in mySQL, with this data :

Table 1:

```
id     |   title
-------+-----------
1      |  Test 1
2      |  Test 2
3      |  Test 3
4      |  Test 4
```

Table 2:

```
id     |  table1_id   |   price
-------+--------------+----------
1      | 1            | 15000
2      | 1            | 2000
3      | 1            | 32600
4      | 2            | 1000
5      | 3            | 4000
6      | 4            | 5500
7      | 2            | 3000
```

Now I want select all records from `Table 1` by `id` sort and select just biggest `price` from `Table 2` so I wrote this query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.price
FROM table1 AS a, table2 AS b
WHERE a.id = b.table1_id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.id ASC, b.price DESC
```

But the result is the first price which is in `Table 2` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with group by or with a subselect (better solution, table1 records without prices will be selected)

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.price
FROM table1 AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT  
        table1_id,
        MAX(price) AS price
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY table1_id
) AS b
    ON b.table1_id = a.id
ORDER BY a.id ASC, b.price DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, MAX(b.price)
FROM table1 AS a, table2 AS b
WHERE a.id = b.table1_id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a groupwise max on second table.

```
SELECT a.*, b.price
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.table1_id
LEFT JOIN table2 b2 ON b.table1_id=b2.table1_id AND b.price<b2.price
WHERE b2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY a.id ASC;
```

The advantage of this query is that you can select all the data from second table, not just the max price.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT t1 . * , MAX( t2.price ) 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.table1_id
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY t1.id ASC
```